# Alter the display property using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I've got two DIVs like:

```
<div class="toggle">Toggle</div>
<div class="data">Something</div>
```

CSS should be:

```
.toggle {  
   padding: 10px;  
   border: 1px solid #999;  
 }  
.data {  
   display: none;  
   padding: 5px;  
}
```

I've been using jQuery to toggle the hide/show property. But I want to ask how to add the CSS property display: none; to this div and also remove the CSS property from it again when the click is made. I know how to do that: using if else. But I am not sure how to add or remove the CSS attributes.

All that I know about jQuery is something like:

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {  
  $(".data").show();  
})
```

Any guide for the CSS jQuery?
If I toggle the hide show property of one div. That will negatively impact the other divs. That are sharing its display as:
`#div1, #div2 {

display: inline;

}`
So if I will hide the div to the left, it will make the div to right get to left, (As I am not having a float: right; for the div). How to make sure, the div stays there too?

Comment: Why don't you just use hide() and show() methods? Anyway here are the docs: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: jQuery's .hide() and .show() functions already toggle the CSS display property.

Comment: Use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) -> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qLaS/)

Comment: You can use toggle() http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Actually I am having two more divs, adding show and hide will make me have to write some code for them too. To display them correctly. For this I want to add display property so that when its back its aligned face to face with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use toggleClass() function which will toggle between class so you can play with multiple properties

```
$('.add-class').click(function(){ $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Nice answer. and helpfull! :) Thanks, so the toggle class will remove and add the class? Right?

Comment: yes it will remove and add the class so you can remove and add multiple properties in css , you can use visibility hidden if you don't want to hamper the layout.

Comment: Yes, I will do the CSS thing myself. Just wanted some help regarding the issue of css. By this I will add CSS and will take control of it in file.css! Thanks anyways.